# Error while making full screen in Atom editor

Tags: atom-editor

I am using Atom Editor since last week. I got one issue on atom screen. I am trying too full screen window but it will show only half screen with line. Please have a look and help me. [image: I have added screenshot here]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to File->Settings->Editor and change Preferred Line Length.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, the line you see is the "line length" line. If you increase the line length the line moves to the right.

Comment: yes, its work but i can set fix length here. I meant to say can i set whole window instead of fix line length

Comment: Ah, I don't think that is possible. But what you can do is 
1) Make that line disappear by either changing css/setting the preferred line length 0/some high number
2) Soft wrap at the width of window instead of the preferred line length (the setting is at the same place)